# Write two interpretations (models) of this language

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-languages

A language consists of a unary function $f$, a unary predicate $p$ and a constant $c$. Write two models $M_1$, $M_2$ such that $M_1 \models \phi$ and $M_2 \models \neg \phi$ given $\phi \iff (\forall x)(\exists y)(p(f(y)) \lor x=c$ 
 
This one is a little bit confusing for me, but I managed to write these two models: 
The first one: 
Set: $\mathbb N$ 
Function: $f(x) = x^2$ 
Predicate: $p(x) \iff x \ge 0$ 
Constant: $0$ 
And so the formula: $(\forall x)(\exists y)(y^2 \ge 0) \lor x=0$ 
Holds, because the first part always holds.

The second one: 
Set: $ \mathbb N $ 
Function: $f(x) = x^2$ 
Predicate: $p(x) \iff x < 0$ 
Constant: $0$ 
Formula: $(\forall x)(\exists y)(y^2<0) \lor x=0$ 
Does not work for $x \ne 0$ 
  
My question is - do these models work? If so, is there an easier way to do this, perhaps using some more common predicates and functions?

Comment: If you interpret $p$ as $\varnothing$, then the situation simplifies...

Comment: I don't think $\varnothing$ is a unary predicate.

Comment: The interpretation of a unary predicate is a subset of the domain. $\varnothing$ is a subset of any set. As a logical formula, this corresponds to choosing $p(x)\iff\bot$.